# How to make sed take input from pipe, and insert into a file

Tags: sed, pipe

is it possible to use the pipe to redirect the output of the previous command, to sed, and let sed use this as input(pattern or string) to access a file?

I know if you only use sed, you can use something like

```
sed -i '1 i\anything' file
```

But can I do something like

```
head -1 file1 | sed -i '1 i\OutputFromPreviousCmd' file2
```

This way, I don't need to manually copy the output and change the sed command everytime

Update:
Added the files I meant

```
head -3 file1.txt
Side A,Age(us),mm:ss.ms_us_ns_ps
 84 Vendor Specific, 0000000009096, 0349588242
 84 Vendor Specific, 0000000011691, 0349591828
```

```
head -3 file2.txt
 84 Vendor Specific, 0000000000418, 0349575322
 83 Vendor Specific, 0000000002099, 0349575343
 83 Vendor Specific, 0000000001628, 0349576662
```

I'd like to grab the first line of file1 and insert it to file2, so the result should be :

```
head -3 file2.txt
 Side A,Age(us),mm:ss.ms_us_ns_ps
 84 Vendor Specific, 0000000000418, 0349575322
 83 Vendor Specific, 0000000002099, 0349575343
 83 Vendor Specific, 0000000001628, 0349576662
```

Comment: `-i` is used to inline edit a file `file2`and will not work this way.  Post some example line and what you like the output to be.

Comment: `head -1 file1 | sed '1 i\OutputFromPreviousCmd' > file2` ?

Comment: @Jotne Updated the question. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Does it have to be sed? `head -1 file1 > temp; cat file2 >> temp; mv temp file2`

Comment: @Beta I don't love the semicolon, but also `head -1 file1 | cat - file2 > temp; mv temp file2`  The `-` prepends the input piped to cat to stdout.  [See also](https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: @stevesliva: That's a neat trick I didn't know.

Comment: @Beta I knew there must be a simple way to do this.

@stevesliva Thanks for ```-```, new to me.

Comment: @stevesliva just curious, how did you learn about ```-```? Is there a doc I can read?

Answer (score 3):

`head -1 file1 | sed '1s/^/1i /' | sed -i -f- file2`

This takes your one line of output, prepends the sed `1i` command, the pipes that sed command stream to sed using `-f-` to take sed commands from stdin.

For example:

```
$ echo bob > bob.txt
$ echo alice | sed '1s/^/1i /' | sed -i -f- bob.txt
$ more bob.txt
alice
bob
```

This looks like pipes and not commands ending in `> temp ; mv temp file2`, but sed is doing that nonetheless when `-i` is used.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
head -1 file1 | sed -i '1e cat /dev/stdin' file2
```

Insert the first line of file1 into the start of file2.

But why not use cat?:

```
cat <(head -1 file1) file2
```